# Restore InnoDB database

Tags: mysql, innodb, restore

Today when trying to start mysql service, I got this error :

> "mysql: job failed to start"

I needed to work with mysql, so I made a backup of my data directory (/var/lib/mysql) and reinstalled the server (mysql-server-5.6), note that I couldn't have used mysqldump because mysql wouldn't start, even with innodb_force_recovery>0

Now mysql starts just fine, but if I put back the old data directory, it shows the error mentioned before. I concluded that the problem comes from corrupted data

Now all I have is this data folder (containing ibdata1, ib_logfile* and such) and I want to restore all the data (not only the structure).

Thank you

Comment: You need to look at the error log in more detail -- you haven't mentioned it *at all*.  Your distro may have put it in `/var/log/mysql/`.  `SELECT @@ERROR_LOG;` (with the server running) should also give you the path to its location, if you can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

"Old" and "new" are the same version 5.6? Try to check privilege of files, folders too.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you tried all `innodb_force_recovery` values including 6. If MySQL still doesn't start follow instructions in my post https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/ . There is a web interface to the data recovery toolkit on https://recovery.twindb.com/, you can upload and recover the database there if you are ok uploading the data.